# Calling a list inside a class

Tags: python, list, class

I am currently stuck on this problem. the answer should first print a 2 and the a 1. But I keep getting a 1 and then a 1.

> Modify the classes below so that when a new instance of Pet
> is created, it is automatically added to its Owner's list of
> pets. Only classes can be modified

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []


        # this is the only change that I have made to the code.
        #only chnages can be made to the code above

        self.pets.append(Pet(self, Owner).name)
      
#Answer should be
#2
#1
owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))

pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)

print(len(owner_1.pets))
print(len(owner_2.pets))
```

I am trying to add new pet names to the list by using append on self.pets. The Owner class already has a name parameter. so this should be able to make sure pet names are being added to the right list. my reasoning is off somewhere but I can not figure out where or why.

Comment: Why are you trying to add a pet to the `Owner` constructor. As you know pets are only created later. So there is no way you can know what pets a owner has at that point in the code.

Comment: You were supposed to add code so when a pet is made, it adds itself to its owner's list of pets. Instead, you added code so... when an *owner* is made, it creates a pet, where the pet's name is... the owner instance? And the pet's owner is... the *class* Owner? And then you add the pet's "name" (which is actually the owner instance) to the owner's list of pets?

Comment: In the owner class, create a function to add data to the pets list. In the pet class, use that function in the __init__ function.

Comment: Can you also add the unaltered code as well? the comment `#only chnages can be made to the code above` is the only area where code changes can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Identify the "trigger" and update there

So the first thing to understand here is the sequence of steps you are taking in instantiating the classes. This will tell you what is the "trigger" that should make an update to the `Owners.pets` list.

Here are the steps you are taking -

```
# Define 2 users
owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))         #<-- No pets defined yet
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))       #<-- No pets defined yet

# Define 3 pets
pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)   #<-- This should trigger something
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)  #<-- This should trigger something
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)  #<-- This should trigger something

print(len(owner_1.pets))
print(len(owner_2.pets))
```

The steps where pets are being defined against an Owner object, is where the magic should happen. That's the trigger. Each time you define a pet, it should automatically update the `Owner.pets` list.

**Therefore, modifying `Owner` class will not yield anything, since you are only defining the Owner objects as the first 2 steps before even the pets are created.**
Here is a solution -

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):  #<-- This __init__ should trigger an update
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner            #<-- After the "Owner" is defined
        self.owner.pets.append(self)  #<-- Update pets from Owner class
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
        
        #This wont help, because Owners are defined before pets
        #Also, this creates a "garbage" pet object which is not defined by your code
        #self.pets.append(Pet(self, Owner).name)

owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))

pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)

print(len(owner_1.pets))
print(len(owner_2.pets))
```

```
2
1
```

---

#### Analysing updates to the list

You can actually analyze the `self` of an object by printing the `object.__dict__` before and after your code has run.

Here is how you can debug -

```
print('BEFORE DEFINING PETS')
owner_1 = Owner(Name("David", "Joyner"))
owner_2 = Owner(Name("Audrey", "Hepburn"))
print(owner_1.__dict__)
print(owner_2.__dict__)
print('')

print('ADDING PET 1')
pet_1 = Pet(Name("Boggle", "Joyner"), owner_1)
print(owner_1.__dict__)
print(owner_2.__dict__)
print('')

print('ADDING PET 2')
pet_2 = Pet(Name("Artemis", "Joyner"), owner_1)
print(owner_1.__dict__)
print(owner_2.__dict__)
print('')

print('ADDING PET 3')
pet_3 = Pet(Name("Pippin", "Hepburn"), owner_2)
print(owner_1.__dict__)
print(owner_2.__dict__)
```

```
BEFORE DEFINING PETS
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145542590>, 'pets': []}
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145541e10>, 'pets': []}
#0 pets for owner 1, 0 for owner 2

ADDING PET 1  
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145542590>, 'pets': [<__main__.Pet object at 0x145543d30>]}
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145541e10>, 'pets': []}
#1 pet for owner 1, 0 for owner 2

ADDING PET 2
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145542590>, 'pets': [<__main__.Pet object at 0x145543d30>, <__main__.Pet object at 0x1433aada0>]}
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145541e10>, 'pets': []}
#2 pets for owner 1, 0 for owner 2

ADDING PET 3
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145542590>, 'pets': [<__main__.Pet object at 0x145543d30>, <__main__.Pet object at 0x1433aada0>]}
{'name': <__main__.Name object at 0x145541e10>, 'pets': [<__main__.Pet object at 0x145539c00>]}
##2 pets for owner 1, 1 for owner 2
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, I see my mistake was over thinking the problem and working on the wrong class. The debugging example was also helpful. I was trying to access it using the list() function and could not.

Comment: Glad to help, its best to focus on the flow of the initializations of the class to understand how an object should interact with other objects. Printing the object as `object at 0x145543d30` will show you which object a class is referring to as that is the memory location for a given object.

Answer (score 0):

You were close - the key is putting the code that updates `Owner` in `Pet`.

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name, owner):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner      

        # this is the key part
        owner.pets.append(self)
        
class Owner:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.pets = []
```